# How to stack column headers with GTK?

Tags: treeview, gtk, pygtk

I use PyGTK's `gtk.TreeView` and `gtk.TreeViewColumn` to build lists with multiple columns. For the columns I want to render standard headers, but stacked on top another row of headers spanning multiple columns. See this illustration:

[image: Stacked column headers]

Unlike column headers 1 to 4, the stacked headers don't need to have any sorting capability. They just need to contain a label. When one of the default headers (headers 1-4) are resized, I want the stacked headers to resize with them so that they stay aligned.

Is this possible with GTK? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the standard `GtkTreeView` widget. All that is possible with this widget is to pack multiple `GtkCellRenderer`s under one column header.

You may be able to create a new widget that just draws the stacked and spanned headers above the `GtkTreeView` widget

Comment: Thanks for your answer Iain. I was afraid that I would have to create a custom widget, something I have no experience with. I'm guessing this won't be easy because it has to integrate wit the `GtkTreeView` widget.